# Only half of last tableview cell is visible when scrolled to the bottom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have a tableview and when i scroll to the bottom of it and release my finger, only half of the cell is visible. If i keep draggaing towards the bottom the whole cell show and then hides when i release my finger.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: how is the content size set and the height of the cells? also the position of the scrollview matters, my guess is that you've probably set the scrollview so that it continues outside the screen. You probably mix bounds and frames somewhere or forget to subtract the size of the button bar on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame of your tableView seems to be set to a wrong frame. Reset the frame like this:

```
CGRect tableViewFrame = [tableView frame];
tableViewFrame.size.height -= heightOfButtonBar;
tableViewFrame.origin.y += heightOfButtonBar;
[tableView setFrame: tableViewFrame];
```

Comment: Origin of my frame was ok, but height was not taking status and nav. bar into account.